# Showing and hiding content while changing style

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation bar with tabs. A tab should become Active when clicking on it i.e. the css should change. Also previous content should be hidden and new content displayed but I'ts not behaving like I want it to:

http://jsfiddle.net/8qz78pkc/

What am I doing wrong?

SO requires some code here is some of the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.profileSubpage:gt(0)').hide();
    $(document).on('click','ul.profileTabs li',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var number = $(this).index();
         $(".profileSubpage").hide().eq((this).index()).show();
         $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your code :

```
eq((this).index())
```

Should be :

```
eq($(this).index())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. Check,

```
 $(document).on('click','ul.profileTabs li',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var number = $(this).index(); 
       $(".profileSubpage").hide();
       $(".profileSubpage:eq("+number+")").show();
       $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
 });
```